# How to convert VS Code ESLint settings to .eslintrc file

Tags: json, eslint, visual-studio-code, eslintrc

How do I convert all my current VS Code ESLint settings to a [`.eslintrc.json`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files) file so anyone who clones the repo will get them too?

I assume I can find them in `json` somewhere and just copy/paste? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eslint configuration is probably stored in the `settings.json` file. To open it simply press Ctrl+Shift+P and type: `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`. You should be able to copy everything in  `eslint.options` to the eslintrc file and it should work.